# How to properly manage extra attribute in MVC Model Object?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project. In which I have a core domain model that represents the entities in my system. I have a Car object and Image object as well. Car has images. I also have a car repository and car service classes. I am trying to provide a functionality to delete a car data from the UI. So I created a SP called DeleteCar. This sp will be called by the car repository class. But the car deletion is based on the user roles. If the user is an admin, then he can delete it, however if he is not he will not be allowed to do so. So I am deciding in my SP if the user is allowed or not in this sample :

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteCar] 
            (
                     @CarId INT
                    ,@UserId INT
            )
            AS
            BEGIN
                DECLARE  @ImagesNamesToBeDeleted Table([FIleName] NVARCHAR(255))


                DECLARE @IsAuthorized bit = 0;
                SELECT @IsAuthorized = dbo.IsAuthorizedToDeleteCar(@CarId, @UserId);

                IF(@IsAuthorized = 0)
                BEGIN
                        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ImagesNamesToBeDeleted)
                        BEGIN
                             SELECT @IsAuthorized AS IsAuthorized , [FIleName] AS FIleName FROM @ImagesNamesToBeDeleted
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                             SELECT @IsAuthorized AS IsAuthorized , '' AS FIleName 
                        END

                END


                SET NOCOUNT ON;
                DECLARE @TranCount INT;
                SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

                BEGIN TRY
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        BEGIN TRANSACTION
                    ELSE
                        SAVE TRANSACTION DeleteCar;

                IF (@IsAuthorized = 1)
                BEGIN

                        -- Delete car data 

                        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ImagesNamesToBeDeleted)
                        BEGIN
                             SELECT @IsAuthorized AS IsAuthorized , [FIleName] AS FIleName FROM @ImagesNamesToBeDeleted
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                             SELECT @IsAuthorized AS IsAuthorized , '' AS FIleName 
                        END
                END

            LBEXIT:
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        COMMIT;
                    END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
                    SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();

                    IF @XState = -1
                        ROLLBACK;
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
                        rollback
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  DeleteCar;

                    RAISERROR (' DeleteCar: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
                END CATCH
            END
```

The Sp is fine. But I am returing the images name so that I can delete these images physically form my server.

so posiioble return result if user is authorized is

IsAuthorized         FileName

1                    A.jpg

if user is not then

IsAuthorized        FileName

0                   -- No data

Here is the repoisptry method that call the SP

```
public async Task<IList<Image>> DeleteCarAsync(int carId, int userId)
        {
            var parameters = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("CarId", SqlDbType.Int) {Value = carId},
                new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = userId}
            };
            using (var reader = await SqlHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync(_connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "DeleteCar", parameters))
            {
                return reader.Select(r =>
                {
                    var image = new Image
                    {
                        FileName = r["FileName"].ToString(),
                        IsAuthorized -- I want to read this value becuase based on it i Will decide if I will physically delete the images or not.


                    };
                    return image;
                }).ToList();
            }
        }
```

What is the best way read the IsAuthorized ?

Should I add a bool property in my image model called IsAuthorized  like what I am dooing right now?

then I will do this

```
if (images[0].IsAuthorized)
{
  // delete images physically

}
```

Any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that way will work. A better user experience would be to not even allow the user to attempt to delete a car that they are not authorized to delete. This way the customer dosen't ever have to see an error message. You could send the `IsAuthorized` flag on your model when you first build the page and change the page accordingly.

You may still want to have the `IsAuthorized` check at delete time, in case the user's permissions have changed between the time page was rendered and the time the delete happens.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. I thought of this and I know that this the right way. But I do still want the user to see the error message. Since it is an  admin user, no problem if he sees this error message, since it will help him to know how he can manage the delete to happen. I just want to know how can I manage this extra attribute in my logic in a proper way ?